# Python-Jenkins raises on create_job if the job name contains spaces

Tags: python, jenkins

I am developing some automation with Jenkins, and I'm trying to create jobs with a simple script.

```
python-jenkins==0.2.1
```

The very odd problem I'm facing, is that i get a very generic

```
jenkins.JenkinsException: create[job name] failed
```

and when I check on Jenkins, the job is actually created, the configuration is ok, but the name stops at the very first space. If the job name doesn't contain any space, no error is raised.

Any of you has experience with this? Or a suggestion on what it could be?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the library is calling a command line tool and not properly escaping spaces in the arguments. I'd report it as a bug. In the meantime, assuming your job name doesn't have any apostrophes in it, you can try passing the name with apostrophes around it, e.g. `'name with spaces in'`, or else use `pipes.quote` or `shlex.quote` on the name before passing it.

Comment: pipes.quote doesn't work.. the job name now is ';job (with the single quotation mark). The other library doesn't seem to have a quote method?

Comment: It depends on which version of Python you're using; `shlex.quote` is where that function lives in Python 3.3 and later. Sorry that didn't work, it was kind of a wild guess.

Answer (score 0):

Since the job names translate to path names, you face the same issues with space in your jobnames, that you are facing with path names. One of the easiest ways to fix this issue is to not allow spaces (and all other characters that will pose issues in filenames).

Comment: Ok, but isn't it a bit odd that it's perfectly fine to create job names with spaces from the UI?

Comment: Once in a while you run into issues with spaces in the UI as well. Not all plugins are tested for it. So I try to avoid the unnecessary troubles right from the start.